# Change urls with mod rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I make a site migration and i need to change all my urls. I know that i can use mod rewrite rule for every link separately but i think this is wrong:
I need to change this type of URL:

```
example.com/categories/ad/hotels,101/hotel-1,25432
```

to this:

```
example.com/turism/hotels/hotel-1
```

As you can see, on new links i have a new folder "turism", id numbers and folders "ad" and "categories" are removed.

I can use this rewrite rule:

```
# 301 --- example.com/categories/ad/hotels,101/hotel-1,25432 => example.com/turism/hotels/hotel-1
RewriteRule ^categories/ad/hotels,101/hotel-1,25432$ /turism/hotels/hotel-1? [L,R=301]
```

But i have 26000 links to change and this is painful. Is there a rewrite rule that can help me speed up conversion? Is it posible to use one rewrite rule for every category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this generic rule for all of your links:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^categories/ad/hotels,[^/]*/([^,]+), /turism/hotels/$1? [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: First i want to thank you. Your rewrite rule is working but it converts every single URL with categories/ad/. For different categories i need different redirection e.g  for  URL: example.com/categories/ad/cars,112/car-1,22335 i will need this redirection: example.com/vihicles/cars/car-1. Every link that has "cars" category need to redirect on a link that has "vihicles" on front like the example. And for the first example every link that has "hotels" category need to redirect on a link that has "turism" on front. I will make this for every category i have.

Comment: Perhaps on your rule we can make one more contition for the category. Search all links with "categories/ad/hotels/ "   to   /turism/.  And a second rule with "categories/ad/cars/" to /vihicles. e.t.c

Comment: I try RewriteRule ^categories/ad/hotels/([^,]+),\d+/([^,]+), /turism/hotels/$1/$2? [L,R=301,NC,NE] but is not working

Comment: To be more clear i need every url that begins: "/categories/ad/hotels..." to be converted to "/turism/hotels/..." but without numbers and coma. Then i will use this rewrite rule for other folders e.g: "/categories/ad/cars..." to  "/vihicles/cars/..." e.t.c

Comment: Thank you. I also see that is working with this rule: RewriteRule ^categories/ad/hotels,101/([^,]+), /turism/hotels/$1? [L,R=301,NC,NE] is this a right rewrite rule?

Comment: Yes your rule also looks good but keeps `101` hardcoded while my rule allows for anything in place of `101` there.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for your help.